# Ubuntu server 20.04 not detecting device over eth0

Tags: linux, connection, ubuntu-server

I am running a C# application on a ubuntu server 20.04 (running on a raspberry pi) which communicates with a [controller](https://5.imimg.com/data5/XY/DT/MY-4084093/huidu-hd-c30-full-color-controller-500x500.png). Both devices are connected via an ethernet cable and afterwards using a socket i search for its set ip 169.254.255.254 which remains always the same.

The application behaves the same as if the two devices are not connected throwing an exception "A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network."

The connection worked on a raspberry pi os (latest version) but i can't use it because of a driver issue with a different component. I am also able to connect to the controller from a windows machine. Sadly i am very new to linux, ubuntu and networking and i can't figure out what could cause this issue.

Is there some kind of a setting that i need to set in order to be able to communicate with the controller?

If more information is needed please ask and i will provide.

Answer (score 0):

Any IP within 169.254.x.x is problematic - in fact, according to [this article](https://kb.iu.edu/d/aoyj), it indicates that the device is not connected to the network at all.